# Filter only certain extension when doing maven assembly

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am running a maven assembly with some mixed resource types; I have a directory structure like the following:

```
project_root/
 |- resources/
     |- scripts/
     |- images/
     |- something/
     |- something_else/
```

The issue is that I have image resources also embedded in the *something* directory, not only the *images* directory; using the following assembly definition:

```
<assembly>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <filtered>true</filtered>

            <includes>
                <include>resources/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The issue here is that the build fails when filtering any `.png` files:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4.1:single (default) on project module_web: Failed to create assembly: Error filtering file '/data/projects/project/module/./resources/something/avatar.png': Mark invalid -> [Help 1]

How can I exclude certain file extensions from being filtered in a maven assembly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in the `exclude` tag. Something like `<exclude>%regex[(?!.*src/).*target.*]</exclude>`. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html.

Or using wildcards like this: `<exclude>*.png</exclude>`.

Comment: The issue is that I still need the files assembled, just not filtered.

Comment: Then why not use another `fileSet` just for including png files?